# Matched Pattern Returns Tuple Of Strings Instead Of A Match As A Whole

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression to fetch some links in HTML document.

```
((http://)(|up)(\.example\.com))*(/uploads/pp2p|/sites/default/files/[-_a-zA-Z0-9%/]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)
```

What I am intending to match is, if the `http` part exists match it if not, don't. If `up` part exists match it if not, don't. If `example.com` exists match it if not, don't. The same about `/uploads/pp2p` and the other one, if exists match if not, don't. Finally, if it has one of the following image formats match it if not, don't. I expect to get a list of links like

```
links = ['http://up.example.com/uploads/pp2p/www.jpg', '/sites/default/files/.png', 'http://example.com/uploads/zzz.jpg']
```

And the elements in the link continue to be filled with different combinations. Anyway, I am getting results as a tuple like

```
[('', '', '', '', '/sites/default/files/favicon', 'png'), ('', '', '', '', '/sites/default/files/logo_2', 'png')]
```

I don't want to get a tuple, I want the match to be represented as a whole. Only a complete link in each list element. How can I avoid getting a tuple as a result of the Regex match?

Comment: I think you need to reorganise the regex to have a single capture group

Comment: Try using non-capturing groups: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group

Comment: @flamusdiu Is it possible to turn non-capturing-group off completely?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Non-capturing groups are not returned. Also, Can you post a example of the source file you are parsing with this? It would make it easier to hel you out.

Comment: Oh, and how are you pushing this through python?

Comment: @flamusdiu I mean I just don't want the smaller groups to be returned, I only need the whole match. I am looking for a way to turn off groups globally.

Comment: @FreeMind Can you post the solution you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are getting images off a web page somewhere.

Here's a quick way to grab all the image src links using [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html):

```
from lxml.html import parse
import re

doc = parse('http://www.androidpolice.com').getroot()
links = []
img_list = []

for img in doc.cssselect('img'):
    links.append(img.get('src'))

for link in links:
    match = re.search(".*androidpolice\.com.*",link)
    if match:
        img_list.append(match.group(0))

for img in img_list:
    print(img)
```

Gives the output:

```
http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/themes/ap2/ap_resize/ap_resize.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpolice.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F05%2Fnexus2cee_gamethumb_thumb1.png&h=128&zc=3
http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/themes/ap2/ap_resize/ap_resize.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpolice.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F05%2Fnexus2cee_gamethumb_thumb1.png&w=150&h=75&f=8|8|8|8|8|8|8|8|8|8|8|8|8
http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/themes/ap2/ap_resize/ap_resize.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpolice.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F06%2Fnexusae0_Google-Photos-icon-logo-150x150.png&h=128&zc=3
```

-----[output truncated]-----

Then you could do `(?:%2F)([\w-]+\.(?:png|jpg))` to get all the image names (of course just an example). I.E. `nexus2cee_gamethumb_thumb1.png`

**Updated Code**

Changed it to search only for `androidpolice.com` in each link. You can find more on using `re` module at [6.2. re — Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: Pretty nice way. Is not there a way to do regex on SRC tags? restricting it to special src tags which start for instance by, `example.com`